# How to pick up elements from std::vector<struct> quickly?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a struct `MyStruct` which have some elements (including `int value1`), and a `std::vector<MyStruct>`. How can I pick up all `value1` from each `MyStruct` and have a `std::vector<int>` which is the vector of `value1`. No write will be operated on the new vector.

The following is possible but the copy is needed. Is there any solution to avoid it?

```cpp
struct MyStruct{
  int value1;
  int value2
};
std::vector<MyStruct> myStruct = func1();
std::vector<int> ans;
for (auto i:myStruct)
{
  ans.push_back(i.value1);
}
func2(ans);  //func2 (const vector<int>&);
```

The struct structure is just an example. The actual structure I use is much more complex.

Comment: Do you mean `for( const auto &i : myStruct )` ? Which copy do you want to avoid?

Comment: If you do `ans.reserve(myStruct.size())` then you'll eliminate some overhead in `push_back`.

Comment: Design smell here: if you need to split up an aggregate, don't aggregate?

Comment: Yes, split up an aggregate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a more optimal solution would be to change the `func2` to take in a `&std::vector<MyStruct>` as an argument *by reference* so that no copy is made. Then you can just access each element by `myStruct[i].value1`.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! Your loop makes temporary copies of elements of `myStruct`, then stuffs `ans` full of pointers into those temporaries. The pointers will become dangling soon afterwards.

Comment: Are you really sure that it's better copying an `int*` than the `int` itself?

Comment: Yes, normally this is bad practice and not recommended but I assumed he wanted to do things this way. I believe my second suggestion would be a much better choice.

Comment: Now that I think about it, integer pointers are even more costly than integers themselves. Sorry for the mistake. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
    auto ret = func1();
    std::vector<int> ans;
    ans.reserve(ret.size());
    for (auto const& elem : ret) {
        ans.emplace_back(elem.value1);
    }
```

emplace_back constructs the element directly from the argument elem.value1 unlike push_back which constructs it from a copy created from the same argument namely elem.value1.

If MyStruct consists of two int values only you can replace it with std::pair<int, int> which is a struct with two public members namely first and be second. Your value1 will be first and value2 will be second. You can do it this way:

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using MyStruct = std::pair<int, int>;

std::vector<MyStruct> func1(/*params...*/) {
    std::vector<MyStruct> ret;
    // grow ret
    return ret;
}
```

and then in main() replace

```
ans.emplace_back(elem.value1);
```

with

```
ans.emplace_back(elem.first);
```

Comment: `emplace_back()` and `push_back()` will do the same thing for `int`s. In both cases you end up with just one copy. The one inside the vector.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is reference type and not just any type but reference of reference and that is exactly where pointers come into picture

```
std::vector<int*> ans;
for (int i = 0; i < myStruct.size(); i++ )
{
  ans.push_back(&myStruct.at(i).value1);
}
```

try this and please let me know it should solve your issue

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! Your loop makes temporary copies of elements of `myStruct`, then stuffs `ans` full of pointers into those temporaries. The pointers will become dangling soon afterwards.

Comment: sorry didn't noticed that let me correcten it please.

Comment: now it is not making any copy of myStruct